# Handler sendEmptyMessage() cannot resolve

Tags: java, android, handler

I have problem with handler. After create i want to send message to handler, but method sendEmptyMessage() cannot resolve. Handler must to update custom list adapter.

There is my code:

```
private Handler mHandler;

mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void close() {}

        @Override
        public void flush() {}

        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord record) {}

        public void handleMessage(Message m)
        {
            catalogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Comment: What does "cannot resolve" means? Whats is the problem? Are there problems in receiving the message?

Comment: @Massimo, message doesn't send because method not found in Handler class.

Comment: Are you sure the class you imported is android.os.Handler? That class has the method sendEmptyMessage(int)

Comment: @Massimo, thank you, was java.util.logging.Handler

fix to android.os.handler, all works correctly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`java.util.logging.Handler` is the wrong class to import. You want to make sure you import `android.os.Handler`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you cannot *resolve* the sendEmptyMessage method. Maybe you have got a wrong import, check that.

On a side note, you just need to post a message to you handler as so :

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(
 new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         catalogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Or even maybe create a background Thread.

As [Massimo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507512/massimo) stated, your import should be :

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

Comment: Yes, mistake in import. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

`mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);` is wrong, because there is no method:

```
 public void handleMessage(int m);
```

Must be:

```
 mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(null);
```

Comment: I don't see why you say it is wrong : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendEmptyMessage%28int%29  from my perspective sendEmptyMessage(null) will produce a compilation error.